# Every 1 second increase the value with a random number using decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, string, dom, numbers, setinterval

So I'm trying to increment the value of a number in an interval of 1 second with a decimal number between (0.01 and 0.05) and I can't seem to figure this out.

The only thing that it does is to show me numbers between 0.01 and 0.05 instead of adding them up to be an integer.

```
setInterval (function myFunction() {
  var number = 0;
  document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = number + 
  Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)/100;
}, 1000)

<b>computer score:</b><p id="computerScore">0</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem** is that you are setting `number` to `0` in each execution, while it should be the current value.

You need to assign `Number(document.getElementById("computerScore").textContent)` to it, so it keeps updating with the added random number.

**Note** that I used `textContent` which is recommended here as it holds only the text content of the element avoiding HTML elements.

```
setInterval (function myFunction() {
  var number = Number(document.getElementById("computerScore").textContent);
  document.getElementById("computerScore").textContent= number + 
  Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)/100;
}, 1000)
```

**Demo:**

```js
setInterval (function myFunction() {
  var number = Number(document.getElementById("computerScore").textContent);
  document.getElementById("computerScore").textContent = number + 
  Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)/100;
}, 1000)
```

```html
<b>computer score:</b><p id="computerScore">0</p>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Really insightful, didn't realized I need to assign Number to the document but it makes sense now

Comment: @karagkalex Yes we used the `Number` constructor To parse the number from the HTML string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the previous value from your score and add your random Number to it :

*PS: I added `.toFixed(2)` to limit your result to two decimals.*

```js
let score = document.getElementById("computerScore");

setInterval (function myFunction() {
  score.innerHTML = (+score.innerHTML + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)/100).toFixed(2);
}, 1000)
```

```html
<b>computer score:</b><p id="computerScore">0</p>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Really helpful know about .toFixed

Answer (score 1):

You set `number` to 0 every time you call the function, you should define `number` outside of the interval

```
var number = 0;
setInterval(function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = number +
        Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1) / 100;
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare number outside the setTimeout:

```
var number = 0;
setInterval (function myFunction() {
  number = number + 
  Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)/100;
  document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = number;
}, 1000)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o946sv8r/1/)

Comment: Thank you this worked! Didn't realized I needed to declare it outside the function, makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this. You forgot to set the number to 0. Then you have to increment your number with the random value you're getting.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgJpep

```
JS :


  var number = 0;

function check(){

  setInterval(function(){
    number = number + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)/100;
  }, 3000);
}

check();

setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = number;
});
```

Let me know if it works for you !